# Ionic API Error: error.json is not a function

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-cli

I'm trying to create a mobile application with API Connection to the database. Sometimes I'm not getting any error and it all works fine with the API but usually, I get this kind of error. (See picture below)

[This is the error I got from the Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsvmU.png)

Here is my code:

```
let headers = new Headers ({
  'Accept' : 'application/json',
  'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.token
});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers : headers });

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.get('https://mywebsite.com/api',  options)
  .toPromise()
  .then((response) =>
  {
    if(response){
      console.log('API Response : ', response.json());
      var _response = response.json();

      resolve(response.json());
    }
    this.loadingSrvc.hide();
  })
  .catch((error) =>
  {
    this.loadingSrvc.hide();
    if(error){
      console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
      console.error('API Error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
      reject(error.json());
    }
  });
});
```

*I'm using **Ionic CLI PRO v4.2.1** and MySQL--phpMyAdmin for database*

**My main dilemma is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I don't even know the reason.**

Comment: might be issue with 'JSON.stringify(error)'. did you console.log(error)?

Comment: Hi @SureshKumarAriya. I've tried to apply your suggestion which is to use console.log(error) and it returned:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.js:1063)
    at dashboard-investor.ts:146
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4629)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)`

Comment: I don't even know what does this mean. I'm sorry cause I'm just a newbie with programming. Hope that you can help me. Thank you :)

Comment: can you paste the API JSON response ?

Comment: I'm not getting any JSON response because it only returns that error.

Comment: Then issue is with API JSON response. you can check Response is valid by adding if block. if(response){}

Comment: I'm getting the error from the catch((error) => {}. where should i put 'if' condition?

Comment: updated answer above.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya I think I've already figured out what causes the problem. Thank you very much for your help :)